# Add user specific fields to Django REST Framework serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to add a field to a serializer that contains information specific to the user making the current request (I don't want to create a separate endpoint for this). Here is the way I did it:

**The viewset:**

```
class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    filter_class = ArticleFilterSet

    def prefetch_likes(self, ids):
        self.current_user_likes = dict([(like.article_id, like.pk) for like in Like.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, article_id__in=ids)])

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        article = super(ArticleViewSet, self).get_object(queryset)
        self.prefetch_likes([article.pk])
        return article

    def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, page_size=None):
        page = super(ArticleViewSet, self).paginate_queryset(queryset, page_size)
        if page is None:
            return None

        ids = [article.pk for article in page.object_list]
        self.prefetch_likes(ids)

        return page
```

**The serializer:**

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Article

    def to_native(self, obj):
        ret = super(ArticleSerializer, self).to_native(obj)

        if obj:
            view = self.context['view']
            ret['has_liked'] = False
            if hasattr(view, 'current_user_liked'):
                ret['has_liked'] = obj.pk in view.current_user_liked

        return ret
```

Is there a better place to inject the prefetching of liked articles, or a nicer way to do this in general?

Answer (score 27):

you can do it with `SerializerMethodField`

**Example :**

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    fav = serializers.SerializerMethodField('likedByUser')

    def likedByUser(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get('request', None)
        if request is not None:
            try:
                liked=Favorite.objects.filter(user=request.user, post=obj.id).count()
                return liked == 1
            except Favorite.DoesNotExist:
                return False
        return "error"

    class Meta:
        model = Post
```

then you should call serializer from view like this:

```
class PostView(APIVIEW):
     def get(self,request):
         serializers = PostSerializer(PostObjects,context={'request':request})
```

Comment: You don't need `try except` when using filter, it doesn't raise an error if the query is empty, simply returns an empty query. and instead of `count()` you can use `exists()` directly.

Answer (score 8):

I'd be inclined to try and put as much of this as possible on the `Like` model object and then bung the rest in a custom serializer field.

In serializer fields you can access the `request` via the `context` parameter that they *inherit* from their parent serializer.

So you might do something like this:

```
class LikedByUserField(Field):
    def to_native(self, article):
        request = self.context.get('request', None)
        return Like.user_likes_article(request.user, article)
```

The `user_likes_article` class method could then encapsulate your prefetching (and caching) logic.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I like the custom field, but `user_likes_article` wouldn't be able to do much in the way of caching/prefetching if all you do is pass it a single article. The reason I have the prefetching inside `get_queryset` is that all the article ids relevant to the request are known there. Is the queryset somehow available in the serializer field?

Comment: I'm presuming you'd use the single article parameter to pick the article from a (cached) collection of user_likes (or such) Your QuerySet is just Articles.objects.all() right? There's nothing request specific there but exactly how you implement user_likes_article will (of course) depend on exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: I realized there was a serious bug in my original question; it didn't at all respect queryset filtering or pagination. I have modified it now, and I think it makes a bit more sense. You can see how the prefetching is tightly coupled with the request (filtering and pagination) and that I can't easily move it into the Like model.

Comment: @kajic Okay the question changes slightly but I don't think the answer really does — certainly the principle behind it doesn't. Assuming users are likely to request more than one page per-session and that your data isn't Too Big™ just cache the user_likes and check for the given article id against that. If your data ends up being Too Big then you're a happy fella and you can do something cleverer then.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Django Documentation - SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield), I had to change the code of rapid2share slightly.

```
class ResourceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    liked_by_user = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_liked_by_user(self, obj : Resource):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        return request is not None and obj.likes.filter(user=request.user).exists()
```